# example from "novel" book class does not compile

Tags: miktex, fontspec

I tried to compile the example document `novel-example.tex` delivered as part of the `novel` package. The compilation terminated with the message: `! Package fontspec Error: The font "LatinModernRoman" cannot be found`. Does anyone know what the cause is?

In my case, the example document is located under `E:\miktex-portable\texmfs\install\doc\lualatex\novel\extras\novel-example.tex`.

Comment: Do you have Latin Modern Roman installed?

Comment: Yes, this font is installed.

Comment: Then it's very hard to tell what the problem is if we don't get to see your preamble and how you call the font and define your document settings.

Comment: Compiled OK `novel-example.tex`  included in the distribution   with 

`This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (MiKTeX 21.3) system commands enabled.
("./novel-example.tex" LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4`  and   `novel.cls    2018/04/26 v1.52 LaTeX document class`


Only change: the magic comment from `% !TeX TS-program = LuaLaTeX`  to `% !TeX TS-program = lualatex`

Comment: I confirm that changing the "magic comment" solved the issue also in my case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am the author of `novel`. Indeed, the original "magic comment" only worked in the TeXworks editor, which understands that LuaLaTeX means `lualatex`. Other programs are case sensitive, requiring `lualatex`. I fixed the magic comment in version 1.80.

Answer (score 2):

There is a minor error in line 59 of the sample code in the [online documentation](https://mirror.metanet.ch/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/novel/doc/novel-documentation.html#hA):

```
Language Support \microtypesetup{config=novel-microtype,stretch=20,shrink=20,final} % microtype
```

This must be changed to read:

```
% Language Support
\microtypesetup{config=novel-microtype,stretch=20,shrink=20,final} % microtype
```

The words "Language Support" should be commented with a % sign in a separate line. The code starting with \microtypesetup should begin in the next line. Now the sample document should compile.

Comment: That is correct. Sadly, I cannot control the online documentation, which is created by someone else. The error does not appear in my own documentation. Also, the above link leads to documentation that is not completely up-to-date. Better read the docs that come with the installed `novel` package.